# Hotkey: Output microphone to headphone jack (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, hotkeys, microphone, audio-output

Does Windows software exist to create a hotkey which will enable/disable passing microphone input to audio output?

A feature which automatically disables the feature if headphones are removed would be preferred, (to prevent internal laptops speakers from amplifying the mic back into the mic, which can destroy speakers.)

Comment: Create a script to do so, make a shortcut to it, and create a hotkey.

Comment: I lack the technical prowess :/